# KVM port-forwarding from ppp0 to VM's bridged NIC not working, but to VM's NAT NIC works?

Tags: linux, iptables, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I've spent a lot of time on this freaky problem, I've created a simple host and VM configuration to try isolate the problem.

**Terminology in this question**

- Host: The bare metal server
- VM: The KVM Guest Virtual Machine
- Incoming connections to ppp0: Tested from a separate internet connection with a different internet IP.

**Port forwarding is enabled on the host**

`root@host $ sysctl net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1`

**Network Setup**

- Host eth0: `10.0.0.155`
- Host ppp0: (internet IP)
- VM Bridged adapter: `10.0.0.121`
- VM NAT adapter: `192.168.122.126`
- VM listening on TCP `0.0.0.0:10003`

**What is not working, that I want to resolve (MAIN OBJECTIVE)**

Incoming connections on the host's port 10003 should be forwarded from ppp0 to the VM's bridged adapter.
iptables-save -c shows the configuration used and counters.
http://codepad.org/SWzL5kEy

**What works**

- The host can connect to the VM on port 10003 on either of it's interfaces:

  `root@host $ nc -z 192.168.122.126 10003; echo $?
  0
  root@host $ nc -z 10.0.0.121 10003; echo $?
  0`
- Other PC's on the network can connect to the VM's bridged adapter 
  `user@otherPConLAN $ nc -z 10.0.0.121 10003; echo $?
  0`
- Incoming connections on the host's port 10003 were successfully forwarded from ppp0 to the VM's NAT adapter. iptables-save -c shows the configuration used and counters.
  http://codepad.org/fwd3R7rF
- Every node on the network (including the host, VM and other PC's) can all ping each other.

**The difference in iptables-save -c outputs**

Flipping between two browser tabs showing the iptables-save -c outputs, I see the configurations are the same. The same counters are being triggered. But the main important difference is the FORWARD rule on line 32 has a higher count when a connection is successfully established to the NAT adapter vs the unsuccessful connection to the bridged adapter.

**My theory**

My theory is that some type of NAT has been incorrectly performed and data is perhaps moving to the VM, but not able to find it's way back through the host and out of ppp0 to the client.

**NIC config in the VM's .xml file**

`<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='11:11:11:11:11:11'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='22:22:22:22:22:22'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>`

**Bridge status**

`root@host $ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP  enabled interfaces
br0             8000.(obfuscated)       no   eth0
                                             vnet0
virbr0          8000.(obfuscated)       yes  vnet1`

**TRACE output**

Here are the TRACE outputs of the two scenarios.
To keep the TRACE outputs short and anonymous, the host's internet ip has been replaced with 'hi', the Test client's internet IP has been replaced with 'ci'.

The following IPTABLES rules were added for TRACE

`root@host $ iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10003 -j TRACE
root@host $ iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10003 -j TRACE`

the client ran this command
`user@remoteClient $ nc -z (host's internet IP) 10003; echo $?`

This trace output was run when the client fails to connect to the bridged adapter
http://codepad.org/FC9BhF7y

This trace output was run when the client successfully connected to the NAT adapter
http://codepad.org/0uHpXXzZ

Comment: Is the host connected wirelessly?

Comment: Did you try tcpdumping it on both sides, to see what comes out and in? Did you check `rp_filter` on VM is not causing you headaches?